# Asterisk callerid on outbound calls using Originate are showing unknow on agi_dnid

Tags: asterisk

I have added a custom PHP file to log all outbound calls to my MySQL database.
This works when I dial from any extension, and I log the caller id and destination number etc.

However when I run a sperate PHP script to Originate a call from my application.
the callerID and dialled number are now unknown.

nano /var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/logoutbound.php

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
include("phpagi.php");
$agi = new AGI();


//$agi->noop("test 1");
$servername = "servername";
$username = "username";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "database";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$mycallerid = $agi->request[agi_callerid];
$mycallername = $agi->request[agi_calleridname];
$phoneno = $agi->request['agi_dnid'];
$myuniid = $agi->request[agi_uniqueid];
$timestart = date('Y-m-d H-i-s');
$channel = $agi->request[agi_channel];
$extension = $agi->request[agi_extension];
$context = $agi->request[agi_context];


$sql = "INSERT INTO voip_outbound
(callerid,callername,uniid,starttime,phonenumber,channel,extension,context)
VALUES ('" . $mycallerid . "','$mycallername','$myuniid','$timestart','$phoneno','$channel','$extension','$context'$

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}


$conn->close();
?>
```

This file is called in 
nano extensions_custom.conf

```
[macro-dialout-trunk-predial-hook]
exten => s,1,Noop(Custom outbound call)
exten => s,n,AGI(logoutbound.php)
```

So when I dial out I get the following in my MySQL. AND this is correct

[image: image from mysql database]

Refid 30 + 32 Show calls made from an extension.
Refid 31 Shows calls made with the originate script - see below

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
#ip address that asterisk is on.
$strHost = "127.0.0.1";
$strUser = "admin";#specify the asterisk manager username you want to login with
$strSecret = "managerpass";#specify the password for the above user
#specify the channel (extension) you want to receive the call requests with
#e.g. SIP/XXX, IAX2/XXXX, ZAP/XXXX, etc
# $strChannel = "SIP/100";
$strChannel = $_REQUEST['exten'];
$strContext = "from-internal";
#specify the amount of time you want to try calling the specified channel     before hangin up
$strWaitTime = "30";
#specify the priority you wish to place on making this call
$strPriority = "1";
#specify the maximum amount of retries
$strMaxRetry = "2";
$number=strtolower($_REQUEST['number']);
$pos=strpos ($number,"local");
if ($number == null) :
exit() ;  
endif ;
if ($pos===false) :
$errno=0 ;
$errstr=0 ;
$strCallerId = "$number";
#$strCallerId = "$strChannel";
$oSocket = fsockopen ("localhost", 5038, $errno, $errstr, 20);
if (!$oSocket) {
echo "$errstr ($errno)<br>\n";
} else {
fputs($oSocket, "Action: login\r\n");
fputs($oSocket, "Events: off\r\n");
fputs($oSocket, "Username: $strUser\r\n");
fputs($oSocket, "Secret: $strSecret\r\n\r\n");
fputs($oSocket, "Action: originate\r\n");
fputs($oSocket, "Channel: $strChannel\r\n");
fputs($oSocket, "WaitTime: $strWaitTime\r\n");
#fputs($oSocket, "CallerId: $strCallerId <$strCallerId>\r\n");
fputs($oSocket, "CallerId: $number\r\n");
fputs($oSocket, "Exten: $number\r\n");
fputs($oSocket, "Context: $strContext\r\n");
fputs($oSocket, "Priority: $strPriority\r\n\r\n");
fputs($oSocket, "Action: Logoff\r\n\r\n");
sleep(2);
fclose($oSocket);
} 
echo "Extension $strChannel should be calling $number." ;
else :
exit() ;
endif ;
?>
```

So my expected result would be to show the dialled number and not unknown
How would i go about fixing this to show the correct information?

Maybe i should call the file from another macro or something.

Thanks for any help

EDIT : After Changing to loca as per my script changed in comment.
So sending to my extension as Local/1069 insead of PJSIP/ i Still get this in my mysql

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your example callerid is not unknown.

Callerid NAME is unknown.

You can try use

```
Callerid: "name" <number>
```

if not help, use Local channels and Set(CALLERID(name)=

About DST param in freepbx report - you have use Local/num@ext-local if you want it be set.

Comment: Caller Name is unknown and i don't really care about it. All i want is the phone number. However the phone number is also unknow when i use the script.

Comment: use freepbx dialplan

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by use free PBX dial plan, could you please elaborate

Comment: you have use Local/num@ext-local instead of SIP

Comment: Hi Artheops, Sorry for being stupid but I really don't know how to change my PHP script to send the dial command in format "Local/num@ext-local". Is there any chance you can help me do it, please. I'll keep trying though

Comment: OK i changed the following in my PHP script just fpr testing. $strChannel = "Local/1069"; $number= "0828574016"; Everything else is left the same, But when i look at my mysql table the destination number is still unknown, where it should be 082 857 4016.
I have edited my original post with screenshot to show the colums and that it is still unknown